# Book where the world is divided into seven parts where each part only lives for one day of the week and is in suspended animation for the rest

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

There was a book I read quite a while ago where due to population problems the population of the world was divided into seven parts.  Each part actively lived one day a week and were in suspended animation for the other six days.

The protagonist gamed the system and was living each day under different identities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possibly [Dayworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayworld_(novel_series)) by Philip José Farmer

> Jeff Caird is a citizen of Tuesday-World N.E. (New Era) 1330. The book
> starts on D5-W1 (Day-Five, Week-One) in the Second Month of N.E. 1330.
> (Each day of the week is the same day number, i.e. Sun-Sat will still
> be D5-W1). The book takes place over a full week, from Tuesday-World
> D5-W1 to Tuesday-World D6-W1. Jeff Caird is an 'organic' (police
> officer) by profession. Each day of the week organics have a different
> outfit. Also, each day of the week has a different fashion trend, TV
> shows, news, and so on, most people only knowing about each in his or
> her own day. However, Jeff Caird is a daybreaker, and not only that,
> he's an immer. The immers are a group of individuals living and acting
> beneath the radar of the government. The goal of the immers is to
> slowly and subtly change the government for the better. There are
> immers in just about every aspect of society in each day of the week.
> Jeff Caird is special in that he is a daybreaker as sanctioned by the
> immers, used to pass messages from day to day. As a daybreaker, Caird
> has mentally created a different identity for himself for each day of
> the week, different jobs, different friends, and different wives all
> included.

Comment: I was going to suggest the short story “The Sliced-Crosswise Only-On-Tuesday World” but have just discovered that “Dayworld” is by the same author and the former influenced the latter.

Comment: @Darren - Also OP said it was a book, not a short story.

Comment: This might be it.  I did look up covers for the book to see if they sparked any sign of recognition but it has been too long.  Don't remember as a police officer though.  I'll see if I can find a copy and read it that will settle it one way or another.  Too bad it isn't on audible though.  PJF seems a little bit unrepresented there.  One book.